# RectangleToScreen and Windows Zoom Factor

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I use this (C# .NET) call to quickly get an image of a control.

Rectangle rectToCapture = myControl.RectangleToScreen(myControl.Bounds);

However, this only works if my Windows display scaling is set to 100%.  If I set the display scaling to 125% this rectangle is totally wrong.  How can I capture the correct rectangle regardless of scaling?

Comment: Your app is *virtualized*, so you get *virtual* Screen measures. Make your app DpiAware. Start from here: [How to configure an app to run correctly on a machine with a high DPI setting (e.g. 150%)?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13228495/7444103)

Comment: Thanks Jimi - that solved it!

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/4d3979d4-88df-44af-8b66-16b1d4d41d57/issue-with-vs2015-windows-form-dpi-and-screen-resolution?forum=winforms

Answer (score 0):

Per @Jimi I had to make the form DPIAware.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/4d3979d4-88df-44af-8b66-16b1d4d41d57/issue-with-vs2015-windows-form-dpi-and-screen-resolution?forum=winforms